# Web server slow when using https

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, xampp

When I view a web page hosted on my web server using https in the afternoon, it loads extremely slow. Loading the same page at the same time using http (unsecure), it loads very quickly. In the morning or late at night we have no problems with it.

We are running XAMPP on a Windows 2008 R2 server

- Processor: Intel Xeon CPU  E5620 @ 2.40 GHz 2.40 GHz (2 processors)
- Installed memory: 8.00 GB
- 64 bit OS

When we notice slowness on the website I have remoted into the server (RDP connection) and looked at performance monitor in Task Manager but I don't see anything maxing out. What could be the cause of slowness? We really need to use https for this application. If I could switch it to http, we wouldn't have this problem but that's not an option.

Comment: When you say XAMPP, do you mean that you're running a pre-configured Apache web stack [like this](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) on Windows?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Generally, it's considered **very** bad practice to do this for a plethora of reasons.

Comment: I understand that and have tried to convince management to let us change it but they are hesitant. We are using a live chat solution from a 3rd party vendor who will only support us if we use XAMPP on Windows. I have a ticket open with them but this issue is regarding an authentication page we added before Live Chat which they don't support...

Comment: Fire up wireshark, and capture the request.  When exactly does the delay happen?

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues where certificate revocation checks to third party CA's have caused slowness.  Check your browser settings to see if that verification is enabled and if so try disabling it and trying your requests again.  It could be completely unrelated to your server.

Comment: That didn't seem to make a difference. It's doing the same thing on every PC I try. I've tried 3 different PCs and a total of 7 different browsers yet the results are always the same.